# Unknown Global Errors when upgrading Ember

Tags: ember.js, ember-data, ember-cli, ember.js-2

when upgrading Ember 2.11 to 2.18 I got alot of Unknown Global errors:

- Ember.Inflector

Unknown Global Global: Ember.Inflector Location: app\routes\base-mt.js at line 17

```
 i18n: Ember.inject.service(),
searchFilter: Ember.inject.service('search-filter'),
inflector: new Ember.Inflector(Ember.Inflector.defaultRules),
init: function () {
    this._super();
```

- Ember.testing

Unknown Global Global: Ember.testing Location: app\routes\base.js at line 30

```
//Don't attempt route reloading if testing
if(!Ember.testing) {
    this.cleanMemory(routeName);
}
```

- Ember.MODEL_FACTORY_INJECTIONS

Unknown Global Global: Ember.MODEL_FACTORY_INJECTIONS Location: app\app.js at line 10

```
var ComposerOverrides = window.ComposerOverrides || {};

Ember.MODEL_FACTORY_INJECTIONS = true;

Ember.TextField.reopen({
```

Ember.production

Unknown Global Global: Ember.production Location: app\router.js at line 1937

```
 });

if(!Ember.production) {
```

- Ember.onerror

Unknown Global Global: Ember.onerror Location: app\application\route.js at line 48

```
 let route = this;
if(Ember.production) {
    Ember.onerror = function (error) {
        route.router.send('error', error);
    };
```

- Ember.Logger

Unknown Global Global: Ember.Logger Location: app\application\route.js at line 167

```
if (error  error.message){
        if(!Ember.production) {
            Ember.Logger.error(error.message);
        }
        let errorModel = Ember.Object.create();
```

- Ember.Handlebars

Unknown Global Global: Ember.Handlebars Location: app\helpers\add-new-line.js at line 5

```
export function addNewLine(value) { var breakTag = ‘ ’; 
let str =     Ember.Handlebars.Utils.escapeExpression(value);
```

- Ember.String

Unknown Global Global: Ember.String Location: app\services\jsonschema-validation.js at line 14

```
// supports, will do for the moment.
    if (!model.includes('-w-')) {
        model = Ember.String.pluralize(model);
```

Answer (score 3):

did you use ember-cli-update? there is a codemod that switches you over to the new module syntax

```
npm install -g ember-cli-update
ember-cli-update --to 2.18
ember-cli-update --run-codemods
# ember-modules-codemod is the one that updates the imports
```